# Deleting all files except those contain specific words in filename

Tags: unix, scripting, expression

I am trying to writing a Korn script (named saferemove.ksh) that receive input as filenames, then delete all those files, except the files with their filenames contain a specific word, such "dog" or "cat".

For each input filename:

```
while (( $1 )) 
do 
    echo "The file now is: $1"
    # Now do the job based on what the problem asks for, by processing $1
    shift
done
```

Can you give me a hint? (might use Regular Express? how?)
Sincerely,
Kohn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  case "$1" in
    *cat*) ;;
    *) rm "$1" ;;
  esac
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply Barmar. I am testing with 'ls' command, instead of 'rm' to see how it works.

Comment: That's no fun, live dangerously!

Comment: I asked my professor about this, he suggested me to use pipe and grep, but I still don't understand what he meant.

Comment: You could do that, but would be overkill for this, unless you really need to match a regular expression rather than just a word.

Comment: Barmar you are too helpful, thank again. Actually this is a more complicated problem assigned by my professor this semester. I broke it down into pieces. Because we are focusing on RegEx now, I guess.

* If you are interested in the assignment, I would like to summarize it: the script will be called saferemove [-a] noword filenames. 

Will remove all files with those filenames except when they contains the word 'cat' or 'dog' in the filenames.

If options -a if provided, then noword is an argument associated with this option will be considered a new word, like 'cat' or 'dog' above.

Comment: I guess he's thinking of `echo "$1" | grep -E 'cat|dog'`.